# Can't start the quest Now or Never

Tags: the-witcher-3

I can not start the mission 'Now or Never'. I believe it is due to the *Travel From Anywhere* mod. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Remove the mod?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you tried disabling the mod you believe is causing the propblem?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no fix for this quest. You fast traveled out of Dijkstra's place I'm assuming.

The quest marker is at the entrance when you are leaving Dijkstra's pool palace. Once you leave this area by fast traveling, there is no way to start the quest again.

There is no issue story wise, if you don't mind not sleeping with Triss (best girl next to Shani). Once you start the main quest and go forward, she'll meet you at Kaer Morhen like nothing ever happened.

Nothing too breaking, you just miss out on the romance opportunity and a little escort mission.

[There IS a post that claims this is possible, but it's very hit or miss.](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/488sc4/forcing_now_or_never_quest_to_start_after_missing/)

> Enable the debug console: (I did not make this mod. It's linked to in
>   the nexus forums as v1.12 broke the console enabler found in the Nexus
>   DB.)
>
> Then type these three commands separately.
>
> addfact(q302_completed)
>
> addfact(q302_post_mafia_completed)
>
> addfact(sq302_start)

I tried to do this at various points throughout my save files and it never worked for me.

Comment: This will give you the `Redania's Most Wanted` quest you need to continue the Tris story. After you complete that quest you will exit the boat in oxenfurt.  If a guy with a letter does not appear run `addfact(q302_post_mafia_completed)` again and you will get the quest.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fix, and its way simpler that you would think. Just go to the oxenfurt docks and walk around radovids ship. The courier will aproach you. Here is where I got aproached in a screenshot:[image]

Comment: Thanks... this works!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Just tell Triss you can't help her. That will lead to meeting her at the sewer entry location where she will say "so you decided to help after all". Then finish the quest.